# Automatically Format .csv file from Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, formatting, export

I have a script for Powershell that exports certain users' information from Active Directory to a .csv file. I would like to apply formatting to this data via Excel.

Is there any way I can make it so the file that Powershell creates is, for one, a formattable Excel file, and for two, automatically formatted (bold/underlined columns, resize column width to fit all data, etc) without any user intervention? Maybe appending it to some kind of template?

The purpose of this file is for end-users to download. Sort of like a user directory. User's can go out to a network drive location and get a weekly-updated list of staff along with info about them (department, phone number, etc), and print that list out. Ideally, this would be done with no work on the end-user's part. Alternatively, I could format this list once weekly myself. But if there is a better way, then I'm all ears.

Comment: I do not know what _not user-friendly_ means? What _exactly_ is wrong with the output and what would the desired output look like. Most of this request is subjective. CSV is just raw data format. Excel makes it look "pretty" if you want it to.

Comment: My apologies for not being more specific. "User-friendly" meaning instead of just the raw text, do simple things like bold/underline the headings, change the width of the columns to actually fit the data, sort alphabetically by a certain column (this one I may be able to do myself but thought I would mention it), and things of that nature.

So, ideally, I would have to change it into an Excel file in order to get this formatting.

Comment: I don't know of any PowerShell cmdlets to accomplish this, but it might be possible to use a utility like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) from PowerShell.

Comment: I am taking a look at that now, thank you! I will report back my results.

Comment: I would go and do it with the Excel module
[Link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/)

I really like it and the post give all the details on how to use it. If you need further information let me know.

Comment: [Import-Excel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/) by Doug Finke uses the EPPlus libraries and functions similar to Import-CSV/Export-CSV. Otherwise you could interact with Excel as a COMObject to do the formatting.

Comment: StefTheo, now THAT is something I am going to look into further. I didn't even realize that I didn't have Excel installed on this machine (it's our ADDS server, so). The fact I can use that with no need for Excel to be installed makes it an attractive choice.

Comment: Why not pipe the csv to `Out-Gridview` users may sort, filter, select and copy to any spreadsheet app.

Comment: Unless the end-users need to _interact_ with the spreadsheet, you could consider creating HTML reports instead - see [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)

Comment: I got it working! I used Import-Excel and it worked like a charm after a good bit of messing around. For anyone interested in my implementation, I am updating the OP with the code I used. Thanks to StefTheo and BenH for the winning recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved (thank you to StefTheo and BenH in my comments). I ended up using the Import-Excel module for Powershell. It worked like a charm and was relatively simple to get working. I'm actually a little bummed out that I only have a use for it to do very simple things, as it is so robust and can do so much!

You can find [Import-Excel here.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/25/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/)

For reference, here is the code I used. This code goes into Active Directory and pulls out all users who have a "Department" listed (this is necessary for me because there are admin/test users with no department listed, and I want to omit them). It grabs their Display Name, Title, Department, Office, Extension, and Email, and exports it to an Excel file. I then style that Excel file using Import-Excel.

```
$excel=Get-ADUser -Filter {(Department -like '*')} -Properties DisplayName, Title, Department, Office, OfficePhone, EmailAddress | select DisplayName, Title, Department, Office, OfficePhone, EmailAddress | Sort-Object "DisplayName" | Export-Excel ("\\w2kapps\shared\EmployeeList.XLSX" ) -WorksheetName "Users From Directory" -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -PassThru
$excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Row(1).style.font.bold = $true
$BorderBottom = "Thick"
$BorderColor = "Black"
Set-Format -Address $excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Cells["A:F"]    -BorderBottom $BorderBottom -BorderColor $BorderColor
$excel.Save() ; $excel.Dispose()
```